# 3 Table JOIN with group by doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    cat VARCHAR(30),
    name VARCHAR(30)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE sales_data (
    id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    sold date,
    sale_s SMALLINT(5)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE expenses (
    id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    date_exp date,
    exp DECIMAL(5,3)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and need to roll up to a monthly level summing the sales column (On table sales_data, to create a Month column. That's pretty easy:

```
SELECT 
    B.id as "Product ID", 
    B.name as "Product Name", 
    B.cat as "Product Category", 
    MONTHNAME(A.sold) as "Month", 
    sum(A.sale_s) as "Sales per Month"
FROM sales_data A
JOIN data B
ON A.prod_id=B.prod_id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY 1,4
ORDER BY 1, A.sale_date ASC;
```

But now, I need the monthly sales data to be merged with the monthly media expenditure data using the Product_ID and Month columns that is in the media_expenditures table.

I'm trying to sum in a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM prod_data A 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 
    id,
    sold,
    sum(sale_s)
FROM sales_data
group by id, MONTH(sold)
) AS B
ON A.id=B.id

RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT
    id,
    date_exp,
    expenses --don't need to SUM since it's only 1 row per month
FROM expenses
) AS C
ON A.id=C.id

ORDER BY A.id, B.sold
```

I't doesn't work and been trying since hours, almost a day in the office. I need it to SUM the first JOIN and then be able to get the row for that month from the media_expenditure table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the month in the second join condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_data A 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 
    prod_id,
    sale_date,
    sum(sales)
FROM sales_data
group by prod_id, MONTH(sale_date)
) AS B
ON A.prod_id=B.prod_id

RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT
    prod_id,
    exp_date,
    media_expenditure --don't need to SUM since it's only 1 row per month
FROM media_expenditure
) AS C
ON A.prod_id=C.prod_id AND MONTH(B.sale_date) = MONTH(C.exp_date)

ORDER BY A.prod_id, B.sale_date
```

Comment: Yes Barmar! Thank you very, VERY much. 

I can see that the main difference is the

AND MONTH(B.sale_date) = MONTH(C.exp_date)

you added at the end of the ON clause. Is this necessary when I work with 3 tables? Because what I can figure out, is that the JOIN multiplied the data (12x12) rows and then SUMed the fields, calculating big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Rod,

If i understood correctly you want to have the Sum of sales in the same select that you have the expendetiures, i believe the follow will help you.

```
SELECT 
    TB1.prod_id as "Product ID",
    TB1.prod_name as "Product Name", 
    TB1.prod_category as "Product Category",
    TB1.Sales,
    TB2.Expenditure
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        B.prod_id,
        B.prod_name,
        B.prod_category,
        MONTHNAME(A.sale_date) as "Month", 
        sum(A.sales) as "Sales"
    FROM 
        sales_data A
        JOIN product_data B
            ON A.prod_id=B.prod_id
    GROUP BY 
        1,4
) AS TB1 
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            A.prod_id, 
            MONTHNAME(A.sale_date) as "Month",
            SUM(B.media_expenditure) "Expenditure"
        FROM
            sales_data A
            JOIN media_expenditure B
                ON A.prod_id=B.prod_id
        GROUP BY 
            1,2

    ) AS TB2
    ON  TB1.prod_id = TB2.prod_id AND
        TB1.Month = TB2.Month
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hoku. I reckon I didn't explain myself very good, but another user answer me what I was looking for.

Cheers mate!